# Does the Standard Library have an opposite to unicodedata.decomposition?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, python-unicode

[`unicodedata.decomposition`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/unicodedata.html#unicodedata.decomposition) sequentially decomposes Unicode characters into its components with the return values being strings of code points separated by space.
E.g

```
>>> unicodedata.decomposition("á") # 0061 is 'a' and 0301 is the 'acute accent' 
'0061 0301'
```

I'm working with Unicode characters that have multiple diacritics (Vietnamese, e.g. ế, ở) and don't always decompose in the desired order (I need to strip the tone mark, but not the other diacritic mark, if any).

So, I'm looking for a function that can compose characters from code points, e.g.

```
>>> compose([0x0065, 0x0302]) # 'e', 'circumflex'
'ê'
```

---

`ADDENDUM`: While I know that writing a function that solves my specific problem (Vietnamese) is trivial, I've posted this question in the assumption that the general problem has been solved by someone before me, and it's perhaps somewhere in the standard library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is actually not far from your link in the python doc, it's the function below: [`unicodedata.normalize`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/unicodedata.html#unicodedata.normalize)

```
>>> unicodedata.normalize('NFC', '\u0065\u0302')
'ê'
```